# Отображение векторного изображения

Tags: изображения, svg

Гуглил, но все же не смог найти конкретной информации касательно отображения векторного изображения, в частности .svg формата на мониторе. Судя по тому, что говорит википедия:

> при выводе на матричные устройства отображения (мониторы) векторная
>   графика предварительно преобразуется в растровую графику,
>   преобразование производится программно или аппаратно средствами
>   современных видеокарт.

То есть, если я правильно понимаю, и, предположим, у нас есть .svg изображение, представляющее собой черный квадрат размером 7000x7000. Выходит, что, когда я открываю его для просмотра, оно конвертируется в бинарное растровое изображение размером 7000х7000 пикселей и занимает соответствующее такому изображению количество оперативной памяти? А если там не черный квадрат, а много разноцветных? В 8-битное или с большей глубиной цвета растровое изображение?
Если я совсем неправильно понял, то объясните, чем обусловлен размер векторного изображения при отображении? Он не меняется и остается таким же, каков размер xml-файла, его описывающего?

**UPD:**
Возможно, я непонятно сформулировал вопрос, задам конкретно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот три изображения, одно черное, в другом присутствую разные цвета, в третьем помимо разных цветов присутствует прозрачность. Какова будет глубина цвета (ну или размер пикселя) при отображении каждой из этих svg картинок?

Comment: Непонятно что за размер вы имеете в виду. Размер файла для изображений (особенно для векторных) слабо коррелирует с размером картинки в пикселях и размером памяти которая нужна для его отображения на экране…

Comment: @Alexey Ten, ну вот есть бинарное, растровое изображение (без сжатия), черный квадрат размером 7000x7000 пикселей, размер файла такого изображения примерно 6мб, при отображении его он займет в оперативной памяти примерно такой же размер. Сколько места в оперативной памяти будет занимать такой же квадрат в формате .svg при его отображении? И от чего это зависит? Исходя из той цитаты, что я привел, векторное изображение конвертируется в растровое при отображении, это так? если да, то по какому принципу?

Comment: Я всё равно не понимаю какая цель данного вопроса. Видеокарте абсолютно всё равно как высчитываются окончательные цвета каждой из 14400 точек изображения.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, смотрите. вот есть у меня растровое 8-битное изображение размером NxN, не сжатое. я, умножив N*N*8bit могу получить размер, который это изображение будет занимать в памяти. Как я могу узнать какое количество оперативной памяти будет занимать векторное изображение при его отображении?

Comment: Зачем вам это знание?

Comment: @Alexey Ten сейчас я разрабатываю приложение, которое работает с большим количеством бинарных растровых изображений. так как эти изображения примитивны, их легко можно представлять как векторные, экономя при этом место в памяти и получая большую скорость отрисовки. поэтому, я хочу знать, от чего зависит размер пикселя при отображении векторного изображения, потому что мне нужно, чтобы он оставался равным одному биту

Comment: Ну так это зависит от вашего алгоритма растеризации.

Answer (score 1):

Оно не хранится в растровом виде. Оно перед выводом (собственно для вывода) растеризуется.
В тот размер и тип растра, в который делается рендер (с настроенным масштабом и положением и областью отсечения).
Так что не будет оно жрать 7000x7000 пикселей, а только время в зависимости от сложности изображения.

Answer (score 0):

Вы видимо введены в заблуждение 7000x7000 пикселями... векторные пиксели совершенно не обязаны согласовываться с пикселями в растровом изображении, но в принципе можно сделать растровое изображение 7000x7000 пикселей, но зачем, куда его потом использовать? По сему зачастую реально растровое изображение векторной графики сильно меньше.